# Can't find icon in Launcher after adding Admob

Tags: android, xml, admob, android-launcher

I built a simple FlashLight app as I'm newbie to android Dev. So I wanted to integrate Admob into app. after doing so, Just after few lines of code, when I generate APK and install on Android phone, i can't find the Icon in launcher and also I can't only see 'Done' and no 'Open' option after installing. SO I need your help.
 Here's the code in androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- This meta data is used to use Google Play Services   -->>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Here's activity_main.xml

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ff18ba75">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flashSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/toggle_switch"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#ff18ba75"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Description" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Developer"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<!-- I Tried removing this Adview lines of code and that fix the error, So I guess the problem is somewhere else.
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I saw in Manifest, there is no launcher activity in your manifest.
please use something like this:
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 0):

The main activity for your app must be declared in the manifest with an  that includes the `MAIN` action and `LAUNCHER` category. For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**If either the MAIN action or LAUNCHER category are not declared for one of your activities, then your app icon will not appear in the Home screen's list of apps.**

If you are adding AdView you need to add another Activity with the  as shown below:

```
<application
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application
```

You might have accidentally replaced the existing activity with the AdActivity.

Comment: Thank you! :) Now I also need help displaying banner ads in-app on clikcking flash button or after sometime. Can you?

Comment: You can post another question for it so that I can post some code for it. You can keep the Adview hidden initially and after the flash button is clicked start a handler with time delay to show the Adview.

Comment: Also dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you.